# Newton-Raphson and bisection for solving for a system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, rootfinding

We know that for a single equation root-finding, we can use the Newton's method, or a combination of Newton with bisection to guarantee convergence. Can we use Newton+bisection for a system of nonlinear equations? I can't figure out how bisection could work on multi-dimensional equations.

For example, if Newton iteration causes one equation to have the $x$-value out of the bisection range, then in the next iteration, does this one equation performs bisection while other equations perform Newton iteration?

Comment: Bisection is based on the intermediate-value theorem, which has no analogue in higher dimensions. There is in general no way to know for certain that a given volume contains a zero.

Comment: @gmvh For a high dimension system, what other relatively simple algorithm can accompany Newton's method to guarantee the root-finding? I want to implement it in C++.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: assuming the function whose zero is thought is scalar. But here, the OP is asking for a *system* of equations, so he's looking for a zero of a function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$. I know of no equivalent of bisection in that context.